# Strategy for unstructured string concatenation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have arrays (of varying lengths) of unstructured strings which I am looking to concatenate into a string expression in order to parse. Some examples could be

```
a  +b              => a+b
a+  b              => a+b
a  +b   c  +d      => a+b, c+d
a+  b   c+  d      => a+b, c+d
a+  b  +c   d      => a+b+c, d
a  +b  +c   d      => a+b+c, d
a+  b+  c  +d      => a+b+c+d
a  +b  +c  +d      => a+b+c+d
a  +b+  c+  d      => a+b+c+d
a  +b   c   d      => a+b, c, d
```

**NB: a, b, c and d are used for brevity. They could actually be strings of any length. Further there could be any number of them as well ... not just 4.**

Note that the element could have leading or trailing operators which would determine whether it should concatenated to the previous or subsequent item in the array to whether it should stand alone or be part of the next expression. (There is also an inherent ambiguity of unary operators and determining whether

```
a -b => a-b or a, -b
```

I do have a grammar (Irony) which I currently use to determine whether the expression being built-up is well-formed. So I concatenate each element, one at a time, parsing the concatenated result to see if it is well-formed. If it is well-formed I still need to continue consuming elements in case the next element has a leading operator. Once I get 2 invalid results from the parser (or the array has no more elements), I conclude that the expression (bar the last 2 concatenations) is valid, store it and then start again. (I need to do it this way because I need to know that the valid expression was a concatenation of specific elements in the array since these map back to objects with other information.)

But it all feels a bit kludgy. E.g in the case of

```
a +b +c +d 

a          => valid
a +b       => valid
a +b +c    => valid
a +b +c +d => valid
```

I would get 4 valid "signals" but for the underlying expression only the last one is the "real" valid "signal"

I am wondering if there are other more elegant strategies for trying to determine whether I should concatenate or not. E.g perhaps I'm not using the parser to its full or perhaps there are some pattern matching strategies I'm not familiar with?

So how should I be approaching this problem?

Thx in advance

S

PS I am using C# but I don't necessarily think that is relevant in this scenario.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the "valid signals"? To me, it seems as if in a first pass just the spaces could be eliminated; furthermore, the ambiguity of the `-` apparently cannot be removed, both cases would have to be considred.

Comment: Will the elements always be one letter long? Perhaps you could do "put all values into one list, remove spaces, insert commas between adjacent letters". So `["a","+b","c"]` becomes `"a+bc"`, which becomes `"a+b, c"`

Comment: @Codor ... thx .. perhaps I haven't laid it out very clearly. The space effectively represents an array element, and I need to know which elements are used in order to access other information about the expression. So just concatenating into a string and  then parsing and reviewing the expression tree doesn't give me the info I need

Comment: @Kevin - thx ... No it is just data to exemplify my problem.

Comment: Which operators do you support?

Comment: is `a+ -b` valid? That is, "a plus negative b"?

Comment: @Bas the standard arithmetic operators plus brackets

Comment: I don't get in which case you could have two invalid results with the example you provided. Could you show some pseudocode or the data that would produce such errors?

Comment: @samy ... you may be right. Just trying to work thru an example and I'm struggling to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have some algorithm that can change its behavior depending on discrete elements (such as tokens, actions, etc) you can see if the [State design pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509234/The-State-Design-Pattern-vs-State-Machine) could be a good match.

The pattern is a bit verbose compared to other methods, but is very easily extendable if needed. We start with an abstract state class: its goal is to let you change from one state to the other when a new token comes into play:

```
public abstract class State
{
    public static string[] operators = new string[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    public List<string> Expressions { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tokens { get; set; }
    public abstract State Process(string token);
}
```

Each state that we can have will derive from this one; we could try to model them upfront: we can describe basically two cases

- either we don't care about the next token, because the previous token ended with an operator (or we are starting our first expression)
- or we want the next token to arrive to start with an operator if we want to continue the expression

Let's create the first state:

```
public class WaitingForAnyTokenState : State
{
    public override State Process(string token)
    {
        return PushTokenToTokenList(token);
    }

    protected State PushTokenToTokenList(string token)
    {
        Tokens.Add(token);
        if (operators.Any(op => token.EndsWith(op)))
        {
            return new WaitingForAnyTokenState() { Expressions = Expressions, Tokens = Tokens };
        }
        return new WaitingForOperationState() { Expressions = Expressions, Tokens = Tokens };
    }
}
```

Basically, we say that if the token ended with an operation, we don't care about the next token since it will be folded into the current expression: we return the `WaitingForAnyTokenState`.

On the contrary, if we don't end with an operation, what happens to the current expression depends on the next token. If it starts with an operation, the expression continues. If not, the current expression ends, and we start a new one.

```
public class WaitingForOperationState : State
{
    public override State Process(string token)
    {
        CloseCurrentExpression(token);
        return PushTokenToTokenList(token); // let's imagine the same method as above is accessible here
    }

    private void CloseCurrentExpression(string token)
    {
        if (!operators.Any(op => token.StartsWith(op)))
        {
            CombineTokensIntoExpression();
            Tokens = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the next case is still decided in the same way as for the first State. The only thing changing is the closing of the current expression if necessary.

Here is a sample code of the architecture you could use:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ttea = new TokenToExpressionAggregator();
    foreach (var l in new string[] { "a+", "+1", "+c-", "d", "e", "+d", "z+", "a+" }) {
        ttea.Add(l);
    }
    ttea.EndAggregation();
    foreach (var expression in ttea.CurrentState.Expressions) {
        Console.WriteLine(expression);
    }
}

public class TokenToExpressionAggregator
{
    public State CurrentState { get; set; }
    public TokenToExpressionAggregator()
    {
        CurrentState = new InitialState();
    }
    public void Add(string token)
    {
        CurrentState = CurrentState.Process(token);
    }
    public void EndAggregation()
    {
        CurrentState = new FinalState(CurrentState);
    }
}

public abstract class State
{
    public static string[] operators = new string[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    public List<string> Expressions { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tokens { get; set; }
    public abstract State Process(string token);

    protected State PushTokenToTokenList(string token)
    {
        Tokens.Add(token);
        if (operators.Any(op => token.EndsWith(op)))
        {
            return new WaitingForAnyTokenState() { Expressions = Expressions, Tokens = Tokens };
        }
        return new WaitingForOperationState() { Expressions = Expressions, Tokens = Tokens };
    }

    protected void CombineTokensIntoExpression()
    {
        Expressions.Add(string.Join(" ", Tokens.ToArray()));
    }
}

public class InitialState : WaitingForAnyTokenState
{
    public InitialState()
    {
        Expressions = new List<string>();
        Tokens = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class WaitingForAnyTokenState : State
{
    public override State Process(string token)
    {
        return PushTokenToTokenList(token);
    }
}

public class WaitingForOperationState : State
{
    public override State Process(string token)
    {
        CloseCurrentExpression(token);
        return PushTokenToTokenList(token);
    }

    private void CloseCurrentExpression(string token)
    {
        if (!operators.Any(op => token.StartsWith(op)))
        {
            CombineTokensIntoExpression();
            Tokens = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}

public class FinalState : State
{
    public FinalState(State state)
    {
        Expressions = state.Expressions;
        Tokens = state.Tokens;
        CombineTokensIntoExpression();
        Tokens = null;
    }

    public override State Process(string token)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

It makes for verbose but eloquent code; personal taste and professional environment may protest. But I have found that it helps to express the functional transitions between your states. It is also more easy to test since each State is small and is not dependent on previous states.

I've taken some liberties guessing at some unclear points in your process (are concatenated operators invalid?) and it is not complete (no brackets), but I think that this structure could help you for the kind of token stream you seem to have.

Comment: TVM. Excellent. I hadn't thought of the state pattern in this context but it make sense give it seems closely related to parsing. Breaks it apart nicely IMV

Answer (score 2):

This should work, pay attention to how this code handle unary operator

```
static List<string> GetExpressions(string[] stringArray)
    {
        const string operators = "+-*/=";
        const string unaryOps = "+-";
        var q = new Queue<string>(stringArray.Length*2);

        foreach (string s in stringArray)
        {
            var work = s;
            if (operators.Contains(work[0]))
            {
                q.Enqueue(work[0].ToString());
                work = work.Substring(1);
            }
            if (operators.Contains(work[work.Length-1]))
            {
                q.Enqueue(work.Substring(0, work.Length - 1));
                q.Enqueue(work[work.Length - 1].ToString());
                continue;
            }
            q.Enqueue(work);
        }

        var res = new List<string>();
        var tmpString = new StringBuilder();
        var lastState = "Op";

        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            var currElem = q.Dequeue();
            var currState = "St";
            if (unaryOps.Contains(currElem))
                currState = "Un";
            else if (operators.Contains(currElem))
                currState = "Op";

            switch (lastState + currState)
            {
                case "OpUn":
                case "OpSt":
                case "UnUn": // only with + & - unary ops: refinement necessary
                case "UnSt":
                case "StUn": // only with + & - unary ops: refinement necessary
                case "StOp":
                    tmpString.Append(currElem);
                    break;
                case "StSt":
                    res.Add(tmpString.ToString());
                    tmpString.Length=0;
                    tmpString.Append(currElem);
                    break;
                case "OpOp":
                case "UnOp":
                    throw new Exception();
            }
            lastState = currState;
        }

        res.Add(tmpString.ToString());

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you remove all whitespaces all valid strings are odd. Next you need to check if all odd positions are leters (a,b etc) and even positions are valid chars(+,-,, etc).

Comment: thx vm. It looks like this is becoming an exercise in learning how to better express my problem!! This is just sample data, you could replace a,b,c d a with strings of any length

Comment: This solution could still possibly be applicable even if the elements can be more than one letter long. You would just have to have a list of strings instead of a single string. Ex. Instead of `"foo+bar"`, you have `["foo", "+", "bar"]`. Instead of checking "all even characters are operators", check that "all even strings in the list are operators".

Comment: ok ... that is interesting. So I would need to process the operators into their own elements whilst keeping track of where they came from in  the original array. I'll have a play.

Comment: Won't this break in the `a+ -b` example from @Kevin's comment?